# Cannot submit a form with Materialize css

Tags: html, jsp, materialize

I use Java EE with JSTL and Materialize css for my project.

When i try to submit a Materialize css form in a jsp file i get an error.

```
> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException:
> Column 'name' cannot be null
```

Here is the form:

```
    <div class="row">
    <form class="col s12" action="update_comment" method="post"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="comment_id" value="${comment.comment_id}" >
      <div class="row"> 
      
        <div class="input-field col s6">
          <i class="material-icons prefix">account_circle</i>
        
          <input disabled value="${comment.name}" id="icon_prefix" type="text" class="validate">
          <label for="icon_prefix">Имя комментатора</label>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s6">
          <i class="material-icons prefix">mode_edit</i>
          <textarea id="icon_prefix2" class="materialize-textarea">${comment.text}</textarea>
          <label for="icon_prefix2">Отредактируйте комментарий</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
      <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="submit-button" id="submit-button">Подтвердить
    <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
      </button>
      &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
      <a id="buttonCancel" class="waves-effect waves-light red btn">
      <i class="material-icons right">close</i>Отмена</a>
   </div>
  </form>
  </div>
```

But when i use normal html code like this it works:

```
 <div>
    <form action="update_comment" method="post" id="commentForm">
        <table class="form">
            <input type="hidden" name="comment_id" value="${comment.comment_id}">
            <tr>
                <td align="right">Category name:</td>
                <td align="left"><input type="text" id="name" name="name" size="20" value="${comment.name}" /></td>
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
                <td align="right">text:</td>
                <td align="left"><input type="text" id="text" name="text" size="20" value="${comment.text}" /></td>
            </tr>
            
            <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="center">
                    <button type="submit">Save</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <button id="buttonCancel" >Cancel</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </form>
</div>
```

What is my mistake? Thanks

Comment: Never call anything in a form "submit"

Comment: That is not the problem i changed the name of the button many times. Why it cannot submit?

Comment: Not familiar with materialise but it looking at the error: `MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException` it seems like a mysql issue, that you don't submit a name to the database. Which you have in the second code block. Maybe add an `<input type="text" name="name" ...>` to you form

Comment: You have not give `name="name"` to your input . Also, your input are `disabled` this will not get submitted to backend ..instead use `readonly`.

Comment: Thank you, mates! As you told me the problem was with: name="name". I added this and it started working. Thank you for your help!